# How to make NewtonsoftJson stop serializing when an error is encountered

Tags: asp.net-core, json.net

We use **AddNewtonsoftJson** in our ASP.NET Core application. When an action has a complex object as a parameter and Newtonsoft fails to serialize the passed in JSON successfully, it simply calls that object with a null value. This is troubling because how do we know if the null value is because of trouble with serialization or because the client sent a null value?

For example, this action gets called with myObj value set as null when there is issue with serializing JSON (I know there is an issue because the SerializerSettings.Error handler gets called).

```cs
public ActionResponse MyAction(MyComplexObject myObj)
{
    // Is myObj null because client sent null or because there was a serialization issue?
}
```

I would like to set things up so that when there is a serialization issue, Newtonsoft or ASP.NET Core doesn't call my action method at all and return an error to the user.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent your action from being called when there's a serialization error using Newtonsoft.Json, you can customize the behavior of the JSON serializer settings to throw an exception on deserialization error. This way, if there's an error in serialization, the action method won't get called, and instead, ASP.NET Core will handle the exception and return a corresponding error response to the client.

Do do that you'll need to configure the error handler in the AddNewtonsoftJson configuration:
When adding Newtonsoft.Json to the MVC pipeline in the Startup.cs (or Program.cs if you're using minimal APIs in .NET 6+), set the error handler to throw an exception:

```
services.AddControllers()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
    {
        options.SerializerSettings.Error = (sender, args) =>
        {
            throw new JsonSerializationException(args.ErrorContext.Error.Message, args.ErrorContext.Error);
        };
    });
```

also, it is good to react to such an exception and return a proper code to the caller. A simple template how this can be achieved here:

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler(appBuilder =>
    {
        appBuilder.Run(async context =>
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 400; // Bad Request
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

            var contextFeature = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
            if (contextFeature != null && contextFeature.Error is JsonSerializationException)
            {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync(new 
                {
                    error = "Invalid JSON format",
                    details = contextFeature.Error.Message
                }.ToString());
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Rafal, I did have something like this setup but was wondering if there is an elegant way to do this rather than raising an exception from the Error handler. Perhaps Core could have had a property withing the args for the Error handler that lets us say Proceed or no.
There is also another issue of this exception being swallowed and not appearing within the OnException override on a custom Attribute I had added to the pipeline. I will create a separate question on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the [ApiController] attribute to your controller, it will automatically issue 400 Error exceptions before proceeding with the data you are sending when the data is not valid.  To trigger it  you will have to  add  validation Attributes  (like Required or Range) to the class properties or to use Fluent validation

Comment: I already have ApiController attribute set on this controller (deriving from ControllerBase)! Do you have any more information on this?

Comment: @cooper_milton To trigger it  you will have to  add  validation Attributes  ( like Required or Range) to the class properties or to use Fluent validation. Otherwise how it is known what is valid what is not?

Comment: so if I don't have a Required or Range property then that property can be null/default which is fine. But, what I am seeing is that the entire param is coming in as null and I wouldn't know if that's because the client sent null or serialization failed.

Comment: @cooper_milton If deserialization is failed, it will return 400. As you understand it can validate only after deserialization

Comment: no, actually like I mentioned in my original post, due to some deserialization failure my action is getting called with a null value - Core is not really returning 400!

Comment: @cooper_milton   Email this issue to MIcrosoft. You are the first.

Comment: @cooper_milton And you have to post your json string and  the classes that are not working properly. Without  these our talk doesn't make any sense